# JTextArea change next append's background color

Tags: java, fonts, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea which is not user editable.
It acts as a console but without input. I want to change the background color for the next append only but have no idea how. I have an idea:

1. Create an instance of type Font and somehow set the background color of this font object
2. Call the method JTextArea.setFont(the instance i previously created) right before i call my next append.
3. call JTextArea.append("message with a background color\n");

I think it works but I have no idea how to set the BackGroundColor attribute for a Font Object. Can anyone give me some insight please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a JTextArea. It doesn't support different font colors.

Instead you need to use a `JTextPane` and you can play with attibutes. Here is a simple example to get you started:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextPaneAttributes extends JPanel
{

    public TextPaneAttributes()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText( "one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\nseven\neight" );

//      DefaultHighlighter highlighter =  (DefaultHighlighter)textPane.getHighlighter();
//      highlighter.setDrawsLayeredHighlights(false);

        //  Define some character and paragraph attributes

        SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);

        SimpleAttributeSet green = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setForeground(green, Color.GREEN);

        SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);

        SimpleAttributeSet left = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setAlignment(left, StyleConstants.ALIGN_LEFT);

        //  Change attributes on some existing text

        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, 3, keyWord, false);
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(8, 5, green, true);
        doc.setParagraphAttributes(20, 1 , center, false);

        //  Add some text with attributes

        try
        {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\nNormal text", null);
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\nGreen text centered", green);
            doc.setParagraphAttributes(doc.getLength(), 1 , center, false);
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\nKeyword text", keyWord);
            doc.setParagraphAttributes(doc.getLength(), 1 , left, false);

            //  Newly typed text at the end of the document will inherit the
            //  "keyword" attributes unless we remove the attributes

            textPane.setCaretPosition(doc.getLength());
            textPane.getInputAttributes().removeAttributes(keyWord);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}

        //  Add text pane to frame

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textPane );
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 250 ) );
        add( scrollPane );

        //  Create a Button panel

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        add(buttons, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        //  Add a Bold button

        JButton bold = new JButton( new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction() );
        buttons.add( bold );

        //  Add Right Alignment button

        JButton right = new JButton( new StyledEditorKit.AlignmentAction("Align Right", StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT) );
        buttons.add( right );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TextPaneAttributes());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

I'll let you read the `StyleConstants` API for other properties you can control including the background color of the text. You can set multiple properties for each attribute set.

Read the section from the Swing  tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for more information and working examples.