# How to write inside rectangular box in jtextarea

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

I am new in GUI . and trying to make chatting application.Please help me how to add label (rectangular box) with some text and which is not editable in jtextarea() ...like the same way we see in any chatting application (chat history)..please please help me

Comment: You can't do it with `JTextArea`, it's designed for plain text. You might consider using a `JList` instead, if you don't need it to be editable

Comment: You might want to use a `JTextPane`. Then you can add the chat messages to the right/left side of the text panel. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240946/jtextarea-change-next-appends-background-color/43241583#43241583